# Gaussian Mixture Modelling Matlab

Tags: matlab, gaussian, mixture-model

Im using the Gaussian Mixture Model to estimate loglikelihood function(the parameters are estimated by the EM algorithm)Im using **Matlab**...my data is of the size:17991402*1...17991402 data points of one dimension:

When I run **gmdistribution.fit(X,2)** I get the desired output

But when I run **gmdistribution.fit(X,k) for k>2**....the code crashes and I get the error"**OUT OF MEMORY**"..I have also tried an open source code which again gives me the same problem.Can someone help me out here?..Im basically looking for a code which will allow me to use different number of components on such a large dataset.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible for you to decrease the iteration time? The default is 100.

```
OPTIONS = statset('MaxIter',50,'Display','final','TolFun',1e-6)
gmdistribution.fit(X,3,OPTIONS)
```

Or you may consider under-sampling the original data.

A general solution to out of memory problem is described in this [document](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/resolving-out-of-memory-errors.html).

Comment: Undersampling is a bit tough for me to do due to the nature of my data..I reduced the number of iterations but I get the same result..any further suggestions?

Comment: A general solution is from this document: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/resolving-out-of-memory-errors.html